# delay in jquery function

Tags: jquery, function, delay

I want to delay this function

jquery:

```
    function simple_tooltip(target_items, name){
        $(target_items).each(function(i){
            $("body").append("<div class='"+name+"' id='"+name+i+"'><p>"+$(this).attr('title')+"</p></div>");
            var my_tooltip = $("#"+name+i);

            $(this).removeAttr("title").mouseover(function(){
                    my_tooltip.css({opacity:0.8, display:"none"}).fadeIn(1000);
            }).mousemove(function(kmouse){
                    my_tooltip.css({left:kmouse.pageX+15, top:kmouse.pageY+15});
            }).mouseout(function(){
                    my_tooltip.fadeOut(10);
            });
        });
    }

    simple_tooltip("a.news_toltip","tooltip");
```

html:

`<a class="news_toltip" href="http://test.com" title="Title">Link</a>`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery delay on function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052440/jquery-delay-on-function)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [setTimeout()](http://klevo.sk/javascript/javascripts-settimeout-and-how-to-use-it-with-your-methods/)

```
var delay = 1000; // one second
setTimeout(function(){
    simple_tooltip("a.news_toltip","tooltip");
}, delay);
```

Comment: Here a blog entry that explains this code : http://klevo.sk/javascript/javascripts-settimeout-and-how-to-use-it-with-your-methods/

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for whatever function you want:

```
setTimeout('simple_tooltip("a.news_toltip","tooltip")', delayTimeYouWant)
```

while delayTimeYouWant is in millisecond: (1000 means 1 second)

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Javascript's `setTimeout`?

Depending on what you want to delay (this isn't entirely clear from your question), you could either put it around a specific fadeIn/Out call or around the call to the tooltip function itself.

```
setTimeout( function_name, timeout_in_ms );
```