# Delay function - jQuery

Tags: jquery, function, delay

I'm using Tweet and Truncate plugin simultanously, so if the tweet it too long it gets truncated after x chars.

```
$().ready(function() {

  $(".tweets").tweet({
    join_text: "auto",
    username: "dave",
    avatar_size: 18,
    count: 1,
    auto_join_text_default: "",
    loading_text: "Loading tweet..."
  });

  if ( $('.tweet_text')[0] ) { 
    alert('yay');
  }

});
```

... so the tweet function loads the tweet, but jquery doesn't find it! Is it possible to delay the next function so it can find it?

Thanks

Comment: Does the Tweet plugin not have a callback function you can use to grab the tweet's content?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery delay on function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052440/jquery-delay-on-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jquery has a delay function http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Comment: the delay function does work. Perhaps you should show what you tried.

Comment: how should I use? can you please update the JS posted in the description? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a delay method in JQuery however a better solution would be to truncate in the tweet callback method.