# How to call a jquery function onload with some delay?

Tags: jquery, function, delay, onload

How to call a jquery function onload with some delay?

I want to call a function like this on load with some delay

```
$(".sample").live('click',function(){
        var id=$(this).attr("id");
```

Comment: So you want to assign the event handler after a delay?

Comment: @Archer I think he wants to execute handler after a delay.

Comment: nope i just want to call a function with some delay onload ,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery delay on function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052440/jquery-delay-on-function)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will wait 1 second and then assign the event handler...

```
function assignSampleClick() {
    $(".sample").live('click',function(){
        var id=$(this).attr("id");
    });
}

// document ready
$(function() {
    setTimeout(assignSampleClick, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try it like this..

```
$(document).ready(function () {
setTimeout(function () {
$(".sample").live('click',function(){
var id=$(this).attr("id");
   }, 3000);
}, 3000);
```

This will fire on page load after 3 seconds delay.

Answer (score 0):

you could use setTimeout function you must refactor your code as something like this

```
    //2 seconds wait before calling doJob
    $(".sample").live('click',function(){ setTimeout(doJob, 2000);});

    function doJob(){
        var id=$(this).attr("id");
        //other statements ...
    }
```

Comment: He wants it to wait *before* assigning the event handler, not before running the attached code ;)

Answer (score -1):

Try to use [Timer Plugin](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/timers)

```
$(this).oneTime(1000, function() {
     // some action here
});
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```js
   var demora = window.setInterval(lerolero, 3000);
function lerolero() {
     $("#ovo").css("display", "block");
 }
```